# Proper use of IsDevelopement() on self hosted .net core 2.2 application

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-core-2.2, .net-core-configuration

I have a self-hosted .NET core 2.2 console app that does not use the web host  builder as I do not need HTTP endpoints for this service.

I'm trying to leverage the environment variable through the `IsDevelopment()` method of the hosting environment but it always comes back as **Production**.

The following is how I've setup my host builder.  I have an environment variable called `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` with a value of **Development** which leads me to ask two questions.

1. What is the proper way to have this set when building my own host so that I can conditionally add user secrets to my configuration when building the host?
2. Second question is if I can use a different environment variable other than `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` since my app is not an ASP.NET core application?

I realize I could probably write code just before building the `HostBuilder` that explicitly looks for an environment variable and set the environment manually, but ASP.NET Core seems to hook this up behind the scenes so I wanted to see if there was a way to get a similar behavior when I'm not using the web host builder.

```
private static IHost BuildEngineHost(string[] args)
{
    var engineBuilder = new HostBuilder()
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, config) =>
        {
            config.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
            config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
            config.AddEnvironmentVariables();
            if(hostContext.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
                config.AddUserSecrets<EngineOptions>();
        })
        .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
        {
            services.Configure<EngineOptions>(hostContext.Configuration.GetSection("EngineOptions"));
            services.AddHostedService<EtlEngineService>();
        })
        .ConfigureLogging((hostContext, logging) =>
        {
            logging.AddConfiguration(hostContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            logging.AddConsole();
        });
    return engineBuilder.Build();
}
```

UPDATE: The following is needed to configure the host before configuration the application

```
.ConfigureHostConfiguration(config =>
{
    config.AddCommandLine(args);
    config.AddEnvironmentVariables();
})
```

This is called before .ConfigureAppConfiguration() and is loaded from any variable called "Environment" which means I don't have to use ASPNET_ENVIRONMENT.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to have the hosting environment initialized with the correct values by calling ConfigureHostConfiguration() before AppConfiguration which properly sets the environment values in the host which I came across in the following doc from Microsoft.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-2.2

```
private static IHost BuildEngineHost(string[] args)
{
    var engineBuilder = new HostBuilder()
        .ConfigureHostConfiguration(config =>
        {
            config.AddEnvironmentVariables();
            config.AddCommandLine(args);
        })
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, config) =>
        {
            config.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
            config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
            config.AddEnvironmentVariables();
            if(hostContext.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
                config.AddUserSecrets<EngineOptions>();
        })
        .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
        {
            services.Configure<EngineOptions>(hostContext.Configuration.GetSection("EngineOptions"));
            services.AddHostedService<EtlEngineService>();
        })
        .ConfigureLogging((hostContext, logging) =>
        {
            logging.AddConfiguration(hostContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            logging.AddConsole();
        });
    return engineBuilder.Build();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> What is the proper way to have this set when building my own host so that I can conditionally add user secrets to my configuration when building the host?

The proper way is to not have all the lines of code you currently have in your `BuildEngineHost` method. If you're using ASP.Net Core 2.2, those settings you've wrote are already set for you. In your `Program.cs` file you should just have this:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
}
```

When you look at `CreateDefaultBuilder` method implementation on [GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/1480b998660d2f77d0605376eefab6a83474ce07/src/DefaultBuilder/src/WebHost.cs) you will see what you're trying to do is already done by default. This is the implementation of `CreateDefaultBuilder` :

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateDefaultBuilder(string[] args)
{
    var builder = new WebHostBuilder();

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(builder.GetSetting(WebHostDefaults.ContentRootKey)))
    {
        builder.UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
    }
    if (args != null)
    {
        builder.UseConfiguration(new ConfigurationBuilder().AddCommandLine(args).Build());
    }

    builder.ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
    {
        var env = hostingContext.HostingEnvironment;

        config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
              .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            var appAssembly = Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName(env.ApplicationName));
            if (appAssembly != null)
            {
                config.AddUserSecrets(appAssembly, optional: true);
            }
        }

        config.AddEnvironmentVariables();

        if (args != null)
        {
            config.AddCommandLine(args);
        }
    })
    .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
    {
        logging.AddConfiguration(hostingContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        logging.AddConsole();
        logging.AddDebug();
        logging.AddEventSourceLogger();
    }).
    UseDefaultServiceProvider((context, options) =>
    {
        options.ValidateScopes = context.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment();
    });

    ConfigureWebDefaults(builder);

    return builder;
}
```

Anyway if you don't want to use this implementation so to answer to your 2nd question you need to use add this line:

```
config.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
```

Just after this line:

```
config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
```

`env` variable is a type `IHostingEnvironment` that need to be injected in your `BuildEngineHost` method.

Comment: The reason I'm using those lines of code is that I'm not building a web host (I have no need for a web server in my application).  Sorry...I thought that was clear by stating I was not using a webhost.  I'll try the code they use in that method you listed however.  I also don't see a UseConfiguration() extension method on my HostBuilder class.

Comment: @Geekn so the last part of my answer is the answer.

Comment: I think so, except I don't have the UseConfiguration() extension method available to me.  Is that in another nuget package?

Comment: @Geekn yep in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions`

Comment: Ahh..I was afraid of that...do you think it's bad that I'm dependent on an AspNetCore library when I'm not hosting an asp.net core application?  That didn't seem to add any extensions for the HostBuilder (just the web host).

Comment: Something else that is a bit confusing to me about that CreateDefaultBuilder().  The ASPNET_ENVIRONMENT is an environment variable which appears to get loaded after the IsDevelopment() method is ran.  The only thing that happens before this is loading command line into the configuration.  I wonder how that actually works.

Comment: I wonder if I need to use ConfigureHostConfiguration() which gets called before ConfigureAppConfiguration.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-2.2  I'll update this if that what was really need in my situation.

Comment: @Geekn what are you trying to create exactly? A windows service? If so then you need to look at this => https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/net-core-workers-as-windows-services/. If you don't need arguments you can skip UseConfguration method. For the last comment, you have `config.AddCommandLine(args);`  after `config.AddEnvironmentVariables();` that is why it works.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing except I'm doing it within Core 2.2 (not pre-release 3.0), but it's essentially the same using a GenericHost instead of a WebHost.  If you notice in the services section, I'm adding a hosted service which inherits from BackgroundService.

Comment: Net Core 3.0 is in preview 7 with Go Live which mean you can use it in production. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-core-3-0-preview-7/

Comment: The answer to my question is the following:                  .ConfigureHostConfiguration(config =>
                {
                    config.AddCommandLine(args);
                    config.AddEnvironmentVariables();
                })